# An error occurs whenever I try to open a jsp page in Eclipse.

Tags: java, eclipse, editor, swt, jface

Whenever I open a `jsp` page in Eclipse IDE, I get the following error:

```
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.5.0_14
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=fr_FR
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product    org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product


Error
Wed Jun 06 18:00:25 CEST 2012
Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.jface".

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument cannot be null
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:3865)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:3799)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:3770)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.ImageLoader.load(ImageLoader.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.ImageDataLoader.load(ImageDataLoader.java:22)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.ImageData.<init>(ImageData.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui.internal.editor.CMImageUtil.getImageDescriptor(CMImageUtil.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui.internal.editor.CMImageUtil.getImage(CMImageUtil.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui.internal.contentoutline.JFaceNodeAdapter.getLabelImage(JFaceNodeAdapter.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui.internal.contentoutline.JFaceNodeLabelProvider.getImage(JFaceNodeLabelProvider.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ColumnLabelProvider.update(ColumnLabelProvider.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ViewerColumn.refresh(ViewerColumn.java:145)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.doUpdateItem(AbstractTreeViewer.java:932)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer$UpdateItemSafeRunnable.run(AbstractTreeViewer.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform.run(Platform.java:888)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.doUpdateItem(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1012)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$UpdateItemSafeRunnable.run(StructuredViewer.java:481)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform.run(Platform.java:888)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.updateItem(StructuredViewer.java:2111)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.createTreeItem(AbstractTreeViewer.java:827)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer$1.run(AbstractTreeViewer.java:802)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.createChildren(AbstractTreeViewer.java:776)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer.createChildren(TreeViewer.java:639)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.internalInitializeTree(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1490)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer.internalInitializeTree(TreeViewer.java:828)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer$5.run(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1474)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.preservingSelection(StructuredViewer.java:1392)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer.preservingSelection(TreeViewer.java:402)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.preservingSelection(StructuredViewer.java:1353)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.inputChanged(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1467)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ContentViewer.setInput(ContentViewer.java:274)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.setInput(StructuredViewer.java:1634)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.internal.contentoutline.ConfigurableContentOutlinePage.setInput(ConfigurableContentOutlinePage.java:664)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.internal.contentoutline.ConfigurableContentOutlinePage.setConfiguration(ConfigurableContentOutlinePage.java:639)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.internal.contentoutline.ConfigurableContentOutlinePage.createControl(ConfigurableContentOutlinePage.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.ui.views.contentoutline.ContentOutline.doCreatePage(ContentOutline.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.ui.part.PageBookView.createPage(PageBookView.java:409)
    at org.eclipse.ui.part.PageBookView.partActivated(PageBookView.java:752)
    at org.eclipse.ui.views.contentoutline.ContentOutline.partBroughtToTop(ContentOutline.java:212)
    at org.eclipse.ui.part.PageBookView$4.partBroughtToTop(PageBookView.java:1015)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartListenerList2$2.run(PartListenerList2.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform.run(Platform.java:888)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartListenerList2.fireEvent(PartListenerList2.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartListenerList2.firePartBroughtToTop(PartListenerList2.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartService.firePartBroughtToTop(PartService.java:212)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPagePartList.firePartBroughtToTop(WorkbenchPagePartList.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPagePartList.fireActiveEditorChanged(WorkbenchPagePartList.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartList.setActiveEditor(PartList.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.makeActiveEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:1277)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.updateActivePart(WorkbenchPage.java:1222)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.partAdded(WorkbenchPage.java:1698)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorAreaHelper.addEditor(EditorAreaHelper.java:217)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorManager.createEditorTab(EditorManager.java:778)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorManager.openEditorFromDescriptor(EditorManager.java:677)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorManager.openEditor(EditorManager.java:638)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditorBatched(WorkbenchPage.java:2854)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2762)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$11(WorkbenchPage.java:2754)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$10.run(WorkbenchPage.java:2705)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2701)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2685)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2676)
    at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:651)
    at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.EditorUtility.openInEditor(EditorUtility.java:361)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.EditorUtility.openInEditor(EditorUtility.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.OpenAction.run(OpenAction.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.OpenAction.run(OpenAction.java:208)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.SelectionDispatchAction.dispatchRun(SelectionDispatchAction.java:274)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.SelectionDispatchAction.run(SelectionDispatchAction.java:250)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.navigator.OpenAndExpand.run(OpenAndExpand.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.RetargetAction.run(RetargetAction.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.CommonNavigatorManager$3.open(CommonNavigatorManager.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.ui.OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper$InternalListener.open(OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$2.run(StructuredViewer.java:842)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform.run(Platform.java:888)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.fireOpen(StructuredViewer.java:840)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handleOpen(StructuredViewer.java:1101)
    at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.CommonViewer.handleOpen(CommonViewer.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$6.handleOpen(StructuredViewer.java:1205)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.fireOpenEvent(OpenStrategy.java:264)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$2(OpenStrategy.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.handleEvent(OpenStrategy.java:298)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1003)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3910)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3503)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2405)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2369)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2221)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:500)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:493)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:194)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:368)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:514)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1311)
```

Everytime I click inside the editor I get a popup and it is very annoying.

I tried eclipse clean but that doesn't work.

Comment: Is this with all JSP files, or just specific ones?  Are custom tag libraries being used?  The build ID also looks weird; what file did you download from eclipse.org?

Comment: i use a lib based on sweetdev, you are sure that s due to tag lib, because if there s something wrong, it ll manifest on the explorer or the logger file.

Comment: Whenever you ask questions, please try to be very specific about your problem. A question like `eclipse editor error` is too general.

Comment: Can you try one thing. Download another copy of Eclipse and see open you current project in that. See if the error repeats itself. It might be some error with some plugin. You might have by mistake changed some property that causes this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a newer version.  http://bugs.eclipse.org/328364 was fixed in Helios SR2 and newer.